# Remove uploaded file in dropzone laravel through ajax

Tags: php, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

I have a laravel application embedded with dropzone.js .
Upload is gets success ,
What I have been trying to do is to delete the uploaded file in dropzone using ajax. 
In dropzone preview pane `Remove file`.
My blade file .

```
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzoneFileUpload">
   <label for="file" class="control-label text-center">Choose a file</label>
   <span class="control-fileupload">   
   <img src="{{URL::asset('/images/image_upload.svg')}}" width="50px" class="upload-icon">
   </span>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var baseUrl = "{{ url('/') }}";
        var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
        var documentType = $("#RC").val();
        Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzoneFileUpload", {
            url: baseUrl + "/dropzone/uploadRC",
            params: {
                _token: token,
                documentType: documentType
            },
            success:function(file, response)
            {
              //$('#documentType1').val(response['documentType']);
              doctype = doctype.concat(response['documentType']);
              $("#documentType").val(doctype);
              doc = doc.concat(response['doc']);
              $("#document").val(doc);
              alert(doctype);
            }
</script>
```

My question here is : How to delete the uploaded file in dropzone ?
I don't see any option in dropzone as ajax.

Comment: Please read this post I think it will help you: https://devnote.in/how-to-delete-uploaded-file-in-dropzone-using-laravel/

Answer (score 1):

I think `myDropzone.removeFile(file)` should work

```
success:function(file, response) {
   myDropzone.removeFile(file)
 }
```

Comment: Do I need to put another ajax call for this?

Comment: you mean, removing from server? absolutely. This just removes the file from the panel UI.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at 
https://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-removedfile

There is an event for removedFile which you could bind to.

Additionally, the default functionality of dropzone is to not enable the removal of files.

Setting this option to true will allow you to manage files within dropzone.

https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-addRemoveLinks.

Example:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
    url: "https://example.com",
    addRemoveLinks: true,

    success: function(file, response) {
        // do stuff
    },
    removedFile: function(file) {
        // remove file from server
    }
});
```